# How do I use the url tag under script tag

Tags: javascript, python, django

I had to change my template slightly to do some URL redirection, so I am using:

```
<script>
    if window.location="www.somesite.com"{
        window.location="www.someothersite.com{% url app.views.some_view argument %}"
     }
</script>
```

But I keep getting an error `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'app.views.some_view' with arguments 'xxx' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

I am using `{% load url from future%}` and I am sure that that particular link works fine otherwise without Javascript.

Comment: Your reverse argument should be enclosed in quotes as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url) .

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to put quotes surrounding your view name:

```
{% url "app.views.some_view" argument %}
```

That's the new syntax starting from [Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#overview).

Comment: No, if quotes were the problem (in Django 1.5), then the error message would be this: `'url' requires a non-empty first argument. The syntax changed in Django 1.5, see the docs.` So it looks like the OP is using an earlier version of Django.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the number of arguments don't match between your view method `app.views.some_view` and the call here in your template.

If you could paste the signature of your view method that would have been helpful. The way you wrote your template code, it suggests the view method signature should be something like this:

```
def some_view(request, arg):
    pass
```

If this is already the case, then check what is really the value of `argument` in your template. Just print it as a test, like this:

```
HERE: {{ argument }} END
```

From the post alone it is not clear whether `argument` is a variable or a string in your template.